# Can you create a JPanel that is rotated?

Tags: java, swing, rotation, jpanel

I was wondering if there might be a way using Java Swing to create a rotated JPanel? 
I'd read other questions/answers on this topic but I didn't understand if you could create one already rotated or not.
It does not need to rotate once it's created, only be created tilted on the x/y axis.
Thanks.

***Thanks, quite helpful!***

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.
have a look at [site standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get this behavior by default.  However, you could extend JPanel and get the desired rotation behavior if you do a little linear algebra:

1. Override the `paint(Graphics g)` method. You could have it first paint to an instance of `BufferedImage`, then use a rotation matrix to rotate that image before drawing it on the underlying panel.
2. Override all methods that handle mouse input and apply the reverse rotation to the coordinates passed in by the associated listeners. This way, the underlying layout manager still 'thinks' that the panel hasn't been rotated, but you've rotated the drawing and event notification so that things still "line up" properly.

I'll caveat all of this by saying I've never done this before, and you could run into unexpected issues not outlined here, but I do have about 10 years of experience with Java Swing and this is how I'd do it if I had to.

Comment: I tried out the first part of this by overriding the paint method and rotating the Graphics object using Graphics2D then calling super with the graphics object.  It looks ok at first but then gets in a mess when any mouse input it detected and repaints the components back in the original position.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way that you can rotate a JPanel itself. However you might be able to rotate the image inside the JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

you can try overriding the paintComponent method of JPanel like so:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class UpsideDownJPanel extends JPanel {
    public UpsideDownJPanel() {}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        int x = this.getWidth() / 2;
        int y = this.getHeight() / 2;
        g.rotate(Math.toRadians(180.0), x, y);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
 }
```

You can also change the degree u want to rotate it